# Tweaking awk to print different things when a regular expression is or isn't matched

Tags: linux, bash, awk

So I'm trying to automate a pretty tedious data gathering process from hundreds of different log files. The following script:

`awk  '/Loop/ { printf $4, }' log*weak*"$factor"x`

will search for the line that says "Loop time of $time" and print the time

The case I'm trying to deal with now though, are when there were run time errors, and the log was never written. That is, the log file is there, but it has no text in it. The problem is that the above script will just skip over the log. I want it to output a space character (to more easily align the csv that's being created out of all of this).

So is there a way to print $4 (the time) when /Loop/ is matched, but " ," when it is not?

Comment: So your files contain at most one line that matches `Loop`?

Comment: Yes, the program uses a template that only has `Loop` once. It can find that no problem and output the time from that line. 

However if `Loop` is not there, it outputs nothing. I want something to be printed out so I can see on the csv that that test needs to be rerun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need the `found` variable :

```
awk '
  /Loop/ {
    print $4
  } 

  END {
    if (! $0) {
      print " "
    }
  }
' YOURINPUTS
```

After reading your comments, this simple snippet should do the trick :

```
awk '{print ($4) ? $4 : " "}' FILE.CSV
```

It's a ternary operator like in C.

Comment: Thanks for your answer -- I like it better not having to rely on the variable. Just so I understand awk a little better, what does the `END` keyword specify? Is that the end of the regexp, or the last block of the script?

Comment: @user1209326, the END block runs after processing all the files on the command line. A bit less obscure is `END {if (NR == 0) print " "}` to check that the line number is zero if the file is empty.

Comment: @glennjackman Ohh I understand. So I guess I wasn't clear enough with my question. I'm making a spreadsheet with each time inn its own cell. The problem is that if the log file is empty, my script isn't creating an empty cell and every subsequent cell is not properly aligned with its column.


So the behavior I'm trying to tease out here is a number if the log file has a number, and a space otherwise. So the csv would look like `1.123, , 2.134`. I'd assume that I would need to implement something that runs while the files are being processed, no?

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
awk '
  FILENAME != oldf { oldf = FILENAME ; If ( found != 0 ) { prínt " " } ; 
                     found = 0 }
  /Loop/ {
    print $4, ;
    found++ 
  } 

  END {
    if ( ! found ) {
      print " "
    }
  }
' YOURINPUTS
```

Comment: I reformatted that just to make it easier to read without the side scrolling.  Otherwise, yeah, this is exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: As you can tell, I'm not very familiar with awk. If I'm using this line, on, say, 500 log files, will `found` reinitialize to 0 every time? I haven't run this yet on the computer with the files, but will one instance of `Loop` throw off every subsequent  `if ( !found)` conditional?

Comment: @user1209326, awk variables are global, so `found` will not reinitialize.